# cursorIndexOutOfBounds error even when using moveToFirst() and checking value of cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working to solve this pity problem for hours now. I have used a lot other cursor methods in my app which are working as a charm but this one has been a real difficult to solve.

```
public int getCategoryCode(String category){
    int d=0;
    Cursor cg=database.query("categoryTable", null, "category_name='"+category+"'", null, null, null, null);
        cg.moveToFirst();   
    Log.d("success", String.valueOf(cg.getColumnIndex("_id")));

    Log.d("success", String.valueOf(cg.getCount()));

    cg.getInt(cg.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    return d;
```

The program return an exception when i try to retrieve the 'integers' saved in the column "_id". I have checked that there are results present in the "id" column because cg.getColumnIndex() return 0 in the logcat. Please help!!

Comment: You don't call `moveToFirst()` just like that. You do `if (moveToFirst())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (EDITED)!!:

```
     public int getCategoryCode(String category){
         int d=0;
         Cursor cg= database.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM categoryTable WHERE category_name = '"+category+"' ",null);

         if(cg.moveToFirst()){
             if(!mCursorActual.isNull(cg.getColumnIndex("_id"))){
               d = cg.getInt(cg.getColumnIndex("_id"));

             } else {
               d = 0;
             }
             cg.close();

                return d;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check:

```
if((cg!= null) && (cg.getCount() > 0)){
  cg.moveToFirst();
  //DO YOUR STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code,

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
if(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

    // Your logic goes here
}
```

Also you can be sure that there is data in your table, use a breakpoint to make sure your query is right, see if the cursor object once the query is complete.